# How to calculate percentage with a Oracle SQL statement with two tables

Tags: oracle

How to calculate percentage with a Oracle SQL statement with two tables?

Why this sql code below doesn't work ?

```
select sum( count(*) / (select count(*) from przedmioty) )*100 from przedmioty 
where id_prz NOT IN (select id_prz from transakcje);
```

I want to count how many percent of the rows in the table "przedmioty" is not on the table "transakcje" (based on "id_prz").

Comment: What does your question mean?  What is the percentage you are trying to calculate?

Comment: I want to count how many percent of the rows in the table "przedmioty" is not on the table "transakcje" (based on "id_prz").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe something like this:

```
select (n/c)*100 pct
from ( select count(*) c from przedmioty ) 
, ( select count(*) n from przedmioty 
    where id_prz NOT IN (select id_prz from transakcje));
```